# How do I avoid Compton drawing shadows on the Gnome-Do window?

Tags: gnome-do, compositing, compton

Compton can draw shadows under windows, which is nice, but unfortunately it draws shadows under the Gnome-Do window, which ends up like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to keep that from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add it to `shadow-exclude` array:

  ```
  # Shadow
  ...
  shadow-exclude = [ "class_g = 'Do'" ];
  ```

  in

  ```
  /home/<user>/.config/compton.conf
  ```
- Or specify it with `compton` launch command. Example:

  ```
  compton -c --shadow-exclude 'class_g = "Do"'
  ```

**Reference:** [`man compton`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/compton.1.html)