# How can I xprop or xwininfo Gnome-Do?

Tags: xorg, awesome, gnome-do, xprop

I need to see the X properties of the Gnome-Do popup window, in regard to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/577589/52719) that I asked earlier. The problem is that as soon as the Gnome-Do window loses focus it closes, so I can't change focus to the terminal to run `xprop`. The answer I keep seeing on the internet is:

```
sleep 5; xprop
```

Then open the Gnome-Do window and wait for `xprop` to start. It seems clever, but simply doesn't work:

```
$ sleep 5; xprop
xprop: error: Can't grab the mouse.
```

The same goes for `xwininfo`:

```
$ sleep 5; xwininfo 

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.
xwininfo: error: Can't grab the mouse.
```

I've also tried running `xprop` using the `Mod+R` shortcut in Awesome WM, but while the Gnome-Do window is open, the shortcut doesn't work. It just types an r into the search box.

I have no more ideas. How do I do this?

Comment: that is a pitty. Will think about it and try tomorrow if no one has the solution by then. Will remove the answer for now. –  Jacob Vlijm just now

Comment: I have to run, but do you have `wmctrl` on your system? we could run the script with the same trick to at least *identify* the window, then combine it with `xprop` to get the data.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Nice, the `wmctrl` command solved it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the script below, it records for 10 seconds (or any other time you set) the output of the `xprop` command on the frontmost window (running the `xprop -root` command). Subsequently, it writes the output, after the time has elapsed, to a file: `outfile.txt`
If you make sure to keep the `Gnome-Do` window active until the script has finished, you can be sure the last record is corresponding to the `Gnome-Do` window.

#### To use it

- Simply copy the script below into an empty file, set, in the head section, the desired path to the output file (`outfile =`, use an *absolute* path). Save it as `record_xprop.py`
- Start the script by the command:

  ```
    python3 /path/to/record_xprop.py
  ```
- Call your `Gnome-Do` window (or any other application you need data from).
- After the time has elapsed, your outputfile will show five times the output of the `xprop -root` command, separated by a dotted line.

#### Note

If you need more time, just change the "5" in the line:

```
 while t < 5:
```

into any other value you need

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

outfile = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/outfile.txt"
data = []; t = 0
while t < 5:
    data.append(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", "xprop -root"]).decode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(2)
    t = t + 1
with open(outfile, "wt") as out:
    for rec in data:
        out.write(rec+"\n"+"-"*20+"\n\n")
```

---

#### Edit

If this does not work for some reason (appearantly the window is not frontmost, as recognized by `xprop`), we could do the same trick with the `wmctrl -l` command (replace `xprop -root` by `wmctrl -l` in the script), to identify the window by its name first.
Once that is done, we can subsequently run again `xprop`, with the `-name` option, to get the needed info: `xprop -name <windowname>`

For both commands, you can run either the `sleep` command, or, if you need more time, run the script again.

Comment: Nice thought, but it doesn't work. Even though the Gnome-Do window is on top and focused, none of the output from your script is for the Gnome-Do window. I've retried many times, and I've tried to explicitly focus the Gnome-Do window by clicking it and typing into it while your script ran.

Comment: I'll keep my answer, as it has more detail and could be useful to someone, but you deserve the credit

Answer (score 2):

Jacob got it in the comments!

Using the `sleep 1; wmctrl -l` command, then opening Gnome-Do, I got this output:

```
0x00e000b9  0 bonus-debian Do
```

Which shows the name of the Gnome-Do window. Then I could use the name to identify the window for xprop:

```
sleep 1; xprop -name "Do"
```

Which gave me the output I was after:

```
$ sleep 1; xprop -name "Do"
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Withdrawn
        icon window: 0x0
GDK_TIMESTAMP_PROP(GDK_TIMESTAMP_PROP) = 0x61
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 14680093
_XEMBED_INFO(_XEMBED_INFO) = 0x1, 0x1
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0xe00004
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0xe00001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 6708
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "bonus-debian"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified minimum size: 19 by 19
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Do", "Do"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Do"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Do"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Do"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Do"
```

Comment: @JacobVlijm Go ahead and make one, I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I used to figure out how Chrome renders it context menu to configure it for use with `picom`. This was hard because technically the menu is rendered by Chrome window and while the menu is open, the mouse is grabbed so I cannot use `xprop` directly.

In practice, I used `xwininfo` to get list of all X windows (including the ones that have no user visible or accessible parts) and then run `xprop -id` against every one of those.

Here's the `bash` one-liner which creates files called `res1`, `res2`, ..., `res9` in the current working directory if you let in run for about 10–20 seconds:

```
for ((i=1; i<=9; i++)); do echo -n "res$i ..."; xwininfo -root -tree | sort -u | grep -oP '^\s*0x[0-9a-f]+\b' | xargs -rn1 xprop -id > res$i; echo " done"; sleep 2; done
```

It shows `res1...` while the snapshotting of the first state is in process (running xprop repeatedly for every single window takes some time) and then `done` is appended after the snapshot is complete. Then you have 2 seconds to change the state of the system (e.g. switch to another window, click a menu open, open a new app) and then another snapshot of the system state is taken. Try to make any changes between seeing "done" and the "res..." on next line.

Keep in mind when you did the change to the system you're interested in. For example, when I executed above, I let it collect current state while I'm still in terminal. When I saw `done`, I switched to Chrome window and waited until seeing another `done` (which was the line `res2` in my case). Then I opened the menu I was interested in and waited with the open menu until seeing `res3... done` to know that I have full snapshot for that state. I then switched back to the terminal and pressed Ctrl+C to stop the data collecting (it would automatically stop after collecting 9 states).

Now I knew that the change I was interested in was between states `res2` and `res3` so I could run `meld res2 res3 &` to view the changes in graphical comparision UI.

Update: here's an even longer one-liner for those pesky windows that `xprop` shows nothing for. This one collects both `xprop` and `xwininfo` for all windows but it's pretty slow to run. It similarly creates files called `res1`, `res2`, ..., `res9` in current working directory:

```
for ((i=1; i<=9; i++)); do echo -n "res$i ..."; echo > "res$i"; xwininfo -root -tree | sort -u | grep -oP '^\s*0x[0-9a-f]+\b' | while read id; do echo -n "."; printf "\n\nWindow id %s:\n\n" "$id" >> "res$i"; xprop -id "$id" >> "res$i"; xwininfo -id "$id" >> "res$i"; done; echo " done"; sleep 2; done
```